# Django: load JavaScript function to HTML Template

Tags: javascript, django

I have tried my JavaScript function in the Console and it seems to be working, but whenever I try to write it in my js file and load it on the index page it doesn't work.
It's a bit confusing But do I need to write anything in the views.py to make the javascript work with the form in my index.html?

index.js

```
document.querySelector('#post-form').onsubmit = function() {
    const post = document.querySelector('#post-body').value;
    alert(`Hello, ${post}`);
    console.log(post);
};
```

index.HTML

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block body %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div id="post-view">
        <h3>New Post</h3>
        <form id="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea class="form-control" id="post-body" placeholder="Post"></textarea>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Network</a>
          
            <div>
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">All Posts</a>
                </li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Following</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        
        <div class="body">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import NewPost


from .models import User


def index(request):
    return render(request, "network/index.html")


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")
```

Comment: share your base html & corresponding view please .

Comment: How does it seem to be working when you do it via the console? Seems like you want to stop the form from actually submitting and "reloading" the page?

Comment: I have edited the post, Yes my goal is to submit the form but I haven't discovered how to do that yet so I was trying to just put an alert at the moment to make sure my form is working when I click on submit, I'm a bit confused what steps I have to take to interact with the form in my HTML page, do I need to have a method in views?

Comment: `block script` should be added in layout

Comment: If you want to stop the from from submitting so you can inspect the logs you can call `event.preventDefault()`: `onsubmit = function(event) {event.preventDefault(); ...}`

Comment: God, yes i added block script and document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { }); in the index.js and now it works..I can interact with my form through JavaScript, Thanks everyone for the fast replies..

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block script %}
{% endblock %}
```

Should be added in the layout.HTML

and add to index.js -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

});
```

And it worked.